# IIS 7.0+ HTTP PUT Completes, but No File Saved

Tags: http, put

I'm struggling to figure out what exactly is happening.  I am using GdPicture to save a scanned document through java script using their COM+ code and source project as my starting ground.  Long story short is their function issues a HTTP PUT command specifying the file name to be saved.

When I execute the command I see that the request is getting to my server, and even has the appropriate content size to include the pdf document.  I even get a 200 response back to my browser, no errors or anything...... yet the pdf doesn't get saved.  Is that because PUT isn't the right way to do this?  I don't have the option to POST the file because the transfer is wrapped in GdPicture's api... so with that said.

  I have done the following
- Ensured that IIS_IUSRS group has write permissions to the "Upload" virtual directory
- Added a handler that specifically allows the PUT verb for "*.pdf"

  Removed the StaticFileHandler for the "Upload" virtual directory

  I aplogize for the links, but I don't have 10 rep points yet
- [PUT Request from FIDDLER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8m13.jpg)
- [Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChLuS.jpg)

** Edit **

More information about GdPicture, I have already contacted them and their function is not the problem.  The implementation is as simple as

```
    var status = oGdViewer.SaveDocumentToPDF_2("http://domain.com/Annotation/Upload/" + FileName, "user", "pass");
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any server logs?  Perhaps that might give a clue.  Also:  How is IIS configured to use GdPicture on the server side?

Comment: @jeffrey_t_b:
Here is the line from the log from my PUT request...
**2014-06-02 14:58:40 ::1 PUT /Annotation/Upload/059f4958-2e54-4ca7-b4ba-a2f30f9a944b.pdf - 80 - ::1 - 200 0 0 4**

Comment: @jeffrey_t_b:
Currently this is being hosted on my local IIS engine ultimately destined for a remote web server.  The included library from GdPicture has been added to the GAC, beyond that I'm not sure what else I would need to do.